# Permission Issue in Docker container for Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, docker, dockerfile

I'm tring to create an Docker image to bootstrap Symfony project.
Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7-apache

LABEL Description = "This image is used to start Symfony3 project"

ENV DIRPATH /var/www/html

# apt-get command
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    vim \
    git
RUN apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev && docker-php-ext-install zip


# Install Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
RUN mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

# Install the Symfony Installer
RUN curl -LsS http://symfony.com/installer -o /usr/local/bin/symfony
RUN chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/symfony

# Create the php.ini file
RUN cp /usr/src/php/php.ini-development /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
```

The build and the container creation works well but I have a permission issue in my container. 
When I'm going to my **app_dev.php**, I have this message:

You are not allowed to access this file. Check app_dev.php for more information.

Apparently, I can access this file only with localhost.
Also, PHP can't delete or create anything in my container.
For exemple I have the following error when I'm running:

```
$php app/console cache:clear
Failed to remove directory "/var/www/html/app/cache/dev_old/doctrine
```

How can I solved that in my Dockerfile?

Comment: what happen if you try to access to the app.php? some tricks here http://olegpuzanov.com/2015/01/24/dockerizing-a-symfony2-application/#comment-2387179153

Comment: Same issue problem with app.php, but not the same message. It's a php error saying about the impossibility to write on the app/dev and app/cache folder. I checked your link and tried it. Same permission problem. And I'm not the only one. You can see people comments on the article.

Comment: Of course, seems not a great article...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally found it after weeks:

Add that in you **Dockerfile**. It solved the permission issue.

```
# Workaround for write permission on write to MacOS X volumes
# See https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/pull/534
RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data
```

Comment: Note: this also fixed my problems with Windows 10 host running Ubuntu 16.04 Guest VM (and docker inside the vm)